# Graphics in Android?

Tags: android, graphics

I'm trying to make a simple graphic in my Android app. I don't know how to start. I searched for some examples,but I found them to difficult for me.

I have 2 arrays with values and I want to represent them on a graphic, on Ox one array, and on Oy the other one.

Can anyone give me some simple example ? Please..

Comment: It would be great if you posted the code you have. It would help people to understand your problem and increase the chances of getting any answers!

Comment: For example I have these arrays :String[] day = new String[] { "12", "13", "14",”15”,”16”,”17” };
String[] money = new String[] { "500$", "450$", "200$", "50$",”250$”,”180$” };
In first array I have the date and in the second array I have the cost in $. I want to reprezent on Ox the date and on 0y the cost. Can I do that? I thinking to be something like to draw a line...For example, in 12 I have 500$, in 13 I have 450$, etc..

Comment: Yep, that looks like a chart!

Comment: Where can I find an example like this?

Comment: Have you looked to the link @Aleadam posted in his answer?

Comment: Yes,I looked, but I need some source code.

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries or do you want to build your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean making "charts" ("graphics is too broad a term).

Check this questions for chart libraries to do it: [Is there a good charting library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424226/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-android)