# Android library for making some 2D graph

Tags: android

I need to make an application which can show some 2D graph with the following View. Please, suggest library which can make exactly this type of graph. Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: Can you please search before you post. This is the first result I got from Google search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android . Take a look at Android Plot. It's pretty simple to use if you are looking for real-time plotting.

Comment: Yes Milanix but i think AchartEngine is the best option in the avilable list with more graph based app. Is it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good charting library for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424226/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-android)

Answer (score 3):

AChartEngine is a charting library for Android applications.Using this u can able to create a graph as given Here http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ check this for complete details of making chart