# How to draw line chart in android phone?

Tags: android

I have a set of data. I want to draw a line chart. The horizontal axis for the time and the vertical axis is my money amount.

```
2013-2-1   50
2013-2-3   80
2013-3-5   90
2013-6-10  120
2013-6-20  40
2013-7-31  77
```

Like the above data, the horizontal is time and the vertical axis is number. How to draw it use line chart? I confuse the horizontal time. It is divergent.

Comment: Try a charting library: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use chart library, there are tonns of them:

- [chartdroid](https://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/)
- [achartengine](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)
- [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home)

and others

Just try to use one of them.

**Same questions:**

- [Charts for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741300/charts-for-android)
- [Charting tool for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551845/charting-tool-for-android)
- [Is there a good charting library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424226/is-there-a-good-charting-library-for-android)